# Retrieving Chromium Browser Data from Console

Tags: chrome

Two questions:

1. How does one retrieve the number of open chromium tabs from the console?
2. How does one retrieve the name of the current active tab (in chromium) from the console?

Unfortunately, with respect to (2), using the command `xwininfo` seems to only work with Google Chrome (not chromium).

Comment: `xwininfo` gets the title from my Chromium windows

Comment: It's weird that `xwininfo` doesn't work. Have you tried `xprop`? For example: `xprop -id $WINDOW_ID | grep _NET_WM_VISIBLE_NAME`.